# How do I add a custom tooltip to angular-nvd3 multibar chart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I cannot get this to work in a multibar chart

```
$scope.countsChart.options = {
  deepWatchData: false,
  chart: {
    type: 'multiBarChart',
    margin: {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 45,
      left: 45
    },
    clipEdge: true,
    duration: 500,
    stacked: true,
    showControls: false,
    xAxis: {
      showMaxMin: false,
      tickFormat: d => $scope.countsChart.selectedGranularity().tickFormat(d)
    },
    yAxis: {
      axisLabelDistance: -20,
      tickFormat: d => parseInt(d).toLocaleString()
    },
    useInteractiveGuideline: false,
    interactive: true,
    tooltips: true,
    tooltipContent: (key, x, y, e, graph) => '<h1>Test</h1>'
  }
};
```

Instead of my custom tooltip, the default tooltip still shows.

[image]

Anybody have success making a custom tooltip?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use the chart.tooltip.contentGenerator method (ES6 equivalent to what I mocked in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IXSBn3EruttBqPR0Aki9?p=preview)):

```
$scope.countsChart.options = {
  chart: {
    ...,
    tooltip: {
      contentGenerator: function (key, x, y, e, graph) { 
        return '<h1>Test</h1>';
      }
   // or if you're writing ES6:
   // contentGenerator: (key, x, y, e, graph) => '<h1>Test</h1>'; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: NOTE: You may need to put this in `chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip` rather than just `chart.tooltip`, depending on other options for your chart.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by "depending on other options"?

Comment: http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/multiBarHorizontalChart